# Which API methods should be used for DocuSign 0Auth?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, digital-signature

Looking into Docusign's API Auth0 documentation and sandboxes and the examples for making a successful 0Auth are based on the following SDK methods:

1. getAuthorizationUri()
2. generateAccessToken()
3. getUserInfo()

These methods work as expected.

However in the Node.js SDK there is also the [AuthenticationApi](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-node-client/blob/ecd6af45dd3993fb9628854983a0a337de55add5/src/api/AuthenticationApi.js) with following methods:

1. getOAuthToken()
2. revokeOAuthToken()

What is difference for both set of methods and in which use cases each should be used? I can't find examples of when they should be used?

Also for 1st set of methods couldn't find a SDK method to revoke the current access token of a user. What is the suggested way to do it using DocuSign's API?

Comment: It looks as though the Node SDK is exposing some deprecated methods. There isn't a way to manually revoke an access token - they can only expire naturally.

Comment: @Drew Nice to know those methods are not used anymore. What should be the programatically way to revoke a token in DocuSign? Don't find documentation about it.

Comment: Access tokens cannot be revoked - they must expire naturally

Comment: @Drew So in the scenario that more scopes are necessary than the ones consented in  current access token, we won't be able to revoke the token. Therefore, the only solution is to issue a new token using the new scopes and end up with multiple tokens active. Am I correct? (Being 10 the limit of access tokens per user)

Comment: The limit of ten tokens per user only applies to legacy OAuth. With current implementations (using the account server / account.docusign.net) there is not a limit on the number of tokens because they properly clear themselves when they expire.

Comment: @Drew - Ok understood. So by using generateAccessToken(), tokens will end up expire naturally (~8 hours) and when integrating there is no need to have a specific a workflow to revoke access tokens. Also, there is no upper limit for the number of access tokens generated for a given user. Nevertheless I assume the best approach continues to use the current token whenever possible. I'm also assuming that when requesting a 2nd access token and refreshing it, it won't impact the ability of using previous access tokens or refreshing previous access tokens. Can you confirm the above assumptions?

Comment: Correct on all counts. We do recommend re-using an access token throughout it's lifespan (8 hours for Auth Code Grant, 1 hour for JWT), but generating a new token won't invalidate an old one.

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign SDKs are based on our swagger spec which include properties and methods from older versions of our APIs. With the previous versions of OAuth it was necessary to make these calls to obtain a permanent access token and to also revoke it.

In terms of the methods used, our SDKs are meant to use industry standard dependencies to handle the token requests and creation. If you'd like to see it in action and how you can tap into it, I would recommend having a look at our quickstarts or git repository for Node. Included in the download are methods for invoking both Code Grants and JWT Grants. The quickstarts operate in Demo only, however when you go to download them it actually configures an OAuth workflow in your Demo account for you -- then it feeds the necessary configuration file into the quickstart download. Under ideal circumstances you would be able to simply run npm start / install and see how it works.

If you need further assistance with this, feel free to open a case on support.docusign.com where someone from my team can work directly with you in terms of consultation and troubleshooting.

Links:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Already used the example and everything works as expected but there is no example to revoke tokens programatically (or documentation). What is the recommended way to it? (Assuming it is possible)

Comment: Hi Pedro, unfortunately not -- the options to revoke tokens existed in our previous versions of OAuth where the tokens existed on a more permanent basis. These systems have since been deprecated. The definitions in our SDKs are automatically generated via our Swagger spec, which would include these older endpoints. Tokens for Authorization Code Grant are good for 8 hours and can be refreshed, tokens generated via JWT are good for 1 hour and cannot be refreshed.